# invoking function with txt file input using GNU parallel

Tags: linux, shell, parallel-processing, gnu

I want to use shell script function like below using gnu parallel.
This is part of my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Figure out script absolute path
pushd `dirname $0` > /dev/null
BIN_DIR=`pwd`
popd > /dev/null

ROOT_DIR=`dirname $BIN_DIR`
export ROOT_DIR
CLASS_NAME=$3
export CLASS_NAME


invoke_driver() {

    $ROOT_DIR/DRIVER_DIR $CLASS_NAME $1 
}

export -f invoke_driver


parallel invoke_driver :::: 'method_list.txt'
```

In 'method_list.txt' file, name of method is listed line by line like below.

```
method1
method2 
...
```

Driver file only gets two arguments as input.
Driver in this code is fuzzing tool which runs endlessly.
So I want to give function each method as input and run this tool in parallel.
For example, if there are 3 methods in a txt file, I would like to write code that fuzzes each method in parallel.

But when I run this code, error occurs.
So please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: You need `export -f invoke_driver` before running `parallel` so it can find the bash function.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I forgot to write it on the post, but it's written on the original code. I will edit my post. Thank you!

Comment: You should show sample contents of `method_list.txt`, and also how you would invoke a single instance of whatever you want done in parallel. You should also ensure you have a proper `bash` shebang at the start of your script if you are relying on `bash` features.

Comment: How many arguments do you expect it to get? And what arguments do you expect it to get?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Driver in this code is fuzzing tool which  runs endlessly. So I want to give function each method as input and run this tool in parallel.

Comment: Please edit your question and show, in full,  the first two exact commands that you expect `parallel` to run for you.